# Using Pyspark to Copy Data from Spark Data frame to Tera data Table via JDBC

Tags: python, jdbc, pyspark, hdfs, teradata

**>I have used Pyspark Code to copy the content from HDFS Dataset that I have converted to dataframe to teradata table using JDBC**

```
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dataiku
from dataiku import spark as dkuspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,HiveContext,SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from functools import reduce
from datetime import date,datetime
import pandas  as pd
#import psycopg2
import sys
from datetime import timedelta
import array
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import teradata
import teradatasql
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
import pprint as pp
import logging
import logging.handlers
import smtplib
import datetime
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/usr/bin/python36'
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
**# Teradata connection details**
user = dataiku.get_custom_variables()['DB_TERADATA_BA_USER']
password = dataiku.get_custom_variables()['DB_TERADATA_BA_USER_PWD']
teradata_server = dataiku.get_custom_variables()['Teradata_server']

**# Connect to Teradata**
tera_con = teradatasql.connect(host=teradata_server, user=user, password=password)
tera_cur = tera_con.cursor()
print("connection to teradata successful")

driver = dataiku.get_custom_variables()['DB_TERADATA_DRIVER']
auditdburl = "jdbc:teradata://"+teradata_server+"/Database=DBName"

#LOGMECH=TD2"
***# Read recipe inputs***
PVS_OP_10052020_1 = dataiku.Dataset("310_PVS_OP_10052020_1")
PVS_OP_10052020_1_df = dkuspark.get_dataframe(sqlContext, PVS_OP_10052020_1)

 # Compute recipe outputs from inputs
 # TODO: Replace this part by your actual code that computes the output, as a SparkSQL dataframe
   bac_NCCT_310_PVS_OP_Test_POC_test1_df = PVS_OP_10052020_1_df  # For this sample code, simply copy 
   input to output


 bac_NCCT_310_PVS_OP_Test_POC_test1_df.write.format("jdbc")\
.option("driver",driver)\
.option("url",auditdburl)\
.option("dbtable",'BAC_NCCT_310_PVS_OP_Test_POC_test3')\
.option("user",user)\
.option("password",password)\
.option('TYPE','FASTEXPORT')\
.mode('append')\
.save()`
```

> **~I'm getting below error while running the code Job failed: Pyspark code failed: At line 74: <class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'>: An error occurred while calling o96.save. Can anybody help in figuring out where I'm doing wrong as I new to Pyspark~**

Comment: Can you add more context around the issues you are running into? Also your code is not properly formatted.

Comment: I'm getting below error while running the above code:  "Job failed: Pyspark code failed: At line 74: <class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'>: An error occurred while calling o96.save"

Comment: On looking at the logs:[2020/10/20-15:45:37.793] [null-err-119] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
[2020/10/20-15:45:37.793] [null-err-119] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/log/spark/user/u111437/stderr (No such file or directory)
[2020/10/20-15:45:37.794] [null-err-119] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding property `"mapreduce.job.queuename": "long_running"` in spark config. This worked for.